# How to filter through multiple MimeTypes for validation during file-upload using CakePHP 1.3?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, mime-types

I have a file upload functionality where I want to allow images and documents and disallow others, checking for extension-only sounds like a bad idea.

The code snippet which I have is:

```
var $actsAs = array(
    'MeioUpload' => array(
        'file' => array(
            'dir' => 'uploads{DS}{ModelName}',
            'fields' => array(
                'filesize' => 'size',
                'mimetype' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif',
                'image/png', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation','application/pdf'),
                'message' => 'Please upload a valid document file'
            ),
            'allowed_mime' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif',
                'image/png', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation','application/pdf'),
            'allowed_ext' => array(' .docx',' .jpg',' .jpeg',' .png',' .gif',' .doc',' .xls',' .xlsx',' .pdf'),
            'validations' => array(
                'MaxSize' => array(
                    'check' => false,
                ),
            ),
            'message' => 'Invalid File. Please upload only document or images'
        ),
    ),
);
```

How do I assign mimetypes to allow : .txt, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .pdf, .png, .jpg, .gif, .jpeg ONLY

MEIOUPLOAD tweak would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried on several locations, finally resorted to core PHP functions.
MeioUpload does not support checking for multiple mime-types. Hopefully, an enhancements may come in coming versions.

```
                $allowMime = array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif',
                                'image/png', 'application/msword','application/vnd.ms-office','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template',
                                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation','application/pdf');
                $file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
                $filename = $attachments[$file_name];
                $data = explode(";",$file_info->file($filename));
                $mime = $data[0];
                if(in_array($mime, $allowMime))
                {
 //Your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mime Type Model Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3amimeType).
Here is the code:

```
This rule checks for valid mimeType

<?php
   public $validate = array('image' => array(
                      'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/gif')),
                      'message' => 'Invalid mime type.'
                                    ),
                            );
```

Comment: Thanks! I gathered it by now. But, I am looking for 'multiple' mimetypes, where I can write LIST of mimetypes to allow.

Comment: that is list of mime-types. I want to put a list of few mime-types. i.e. allowed mime-types. For example, if I have a filter with mimetypes allowed.. and someone uploads say.. a .exe file then, I want to BLOCK it straight away.

Comment: You can write all the allowed mimeTypes in array() where you specified `'image/gif'` separated by commas.

Comment: Please check my question, I have edited it with the code that I am using currently then, I tried adding .sh file and .php and even .exe file, though .exe was blocked by gmail but, it cleared .php and .sh files into the mail box. Question is, it should give an error instead of letting it pass through? Oh, I am using it with mail by the way...